# What's the difference between ubuntu 13.10 amd 12.04 LTS??? and

Tags: 12.04, 13.10, laptop

What's the difference between ubuntu 13.10 amd 12.04 LTS
and which one is best for my laptop (Asus k46cb i7) imeans which one recognizes my laptop drivers completely?

Comment: Just a suggestion. If you are a newbie (like me), go try 12.04 LTS because GPU support in higher version "might" be terrible.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Either one will almost certainly recognise your drivers.

If you want to have stability and long-term support choose 12.04. You can upgrade it to 14.04 next year if you want to - that will be an LTS as well.

13.10 is not a long-term support release. It is like a stepping stone on the way to 14.04.

LTS releases come every two years and they are always even numbered and released in April, hence the '04' bit. So 10.04, 12.04, 14.04, when it is released, are all LTS.

Other releases are more about introducing newer techniques and sub-systems into ubuntu as part of the development process.

Answer (score 2):

LTS Releases are more stable than the newer ones.. 
The newer releases have more changes but they're not guaranteed to work as expected 
For a better view..
Want stability ? 
Go for LTS version ..
Need newer things ?
Go for newer versions
Simple as that :)