# Ubuntu 12.04 LTS Versus Ubuntu 13.10

Tags: performance, ram, versions

I'm new to Ubuntu and I'm not sure which version to install. 
Which offers better performance? Which would you recomend?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: 13.10 64 bits has more performance acording to benchmarks. I recomend for personal desktop use.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to have stability and long-term support choose 12.04. You can upgrade it to 14.04 next year if you want to - that will be an LTS as well.

13.10 is not a long-term support release. It is like a stepping stone on the way to 14.04.

LTS releases come every two years and they are always even numbered and released in April, hence the '04' bit. So 10.04, 12.04, 14.04, when it is released, are all LTS.

Other releases are more about introducing newer techniques and sub-systems into ubuntu as part of the development process.

[source](https://askubuntu.com/questions/377854/whats-the-difference-between-ubuntu-13-10-amd-12-04-lts-and)

Overall, if you're thinking of moving from Ubuntu 12.04.2 LTS to Ubuntu 13.10 on the basis of better performance, that's true if you're using the open-source Intel/Radeon/Nouveau graphics drivers..

Comment: Ubuntu 13.10 has performance improvement not only in graphics drivers...

Comment: That's phoronix benchmarking result..